# Next.js automatically picks my GitHub remote repository and doesn't let me remove it

Tags: git, github, next.js

I'm using Next.js to create an app on my machine using the command

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

I've also tried using the command

```
npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"
```

When the app is finished, I type `git remote -v` and it shows me a random GitHub repository that I built a month ago and has nothing to do with this app.
When I try to remove this repo by typing `git remote remove <repo-name>`, it says `error: No such remote: <repo-name>`

If I try pushing code to my Next.js app, it pushes it to this random repository instead of the one that Next created for me.

I tried installing Vercel, uninstalling it, setting it to have access to all repositories. Nothing worked.

I'm using Windows. I appreciate any advice.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kqlx.png)

Comment: `origin` is the *remote*. `https://github.com/whatever` is the *URL stored under the remote*. The `git remote remove` command requires that you name the *remote*, i.e., `git remote remove origin`. But removing `origin` is probably wrong: you probably want `git remote set-url origin <new-url>`. Note, though, that the stored URL in `origin` *is* where the repository was *cloned from*, so this may merely be papering over a totally different npm-specific problem.